# Why does the todo item below a crossed one become crossed when a todo-item above is deleted?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Why does the todo item below a crossed one become crossed when a todo-item above is deleted ?

For example:

item1
item2
item3
item4

Cross item3:

item1
item2
item3 X
item 4

Remove item 2:

item1
item3
item4 X

What did I do wrong in my Vue code ? I just started learning Vue yesterday, so my mistake is most likely basic.

```html
<div id="app">
    <todo-list>
    
    </todo-list>
</div>

<style>
    .crossed {
        text-decoration : line-through;
    }
    
    .todo:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>
    
Vue.component('todo-list',{

    data: function () {
        return {
            newText: '',
            todos:[],
            todoId: 0
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <form v-on:submit.prevent="addTodo">
                <input v-model="newText">
                <button>ADD TODO</button>
            </form>
            <ul>
                <todo class="todo" v-for="(todo,index) in todos" :text="todo.text" :key="todo.todoId" @remove="removeTodo(index)"></todo>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        addTodo: function() {
            this.todos.push({
                text: this.newText,
                done: false,
                id: this.todoId++
            });
            this.newText = '';
        },
        removeTodo: function(index) {
            this.todos.splice(index,1);
        }
    }

});

Vue.component('todo',{
    props: ['text'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            done: false
        }
    },
    template: `
        <li> 
            <span v-on:click="done = !done" :class="{crossed: done}">
                {{text}}
            </span>
            <button v-on:click="$emit('remove')">Remove</button>
        </li>
    `
}) 

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
    



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you did not use `:key="todo.id"` but `:key="todo.todoId` thus splicing the third makes the fourth the third by replacing text property. Else it should work.

btw `todo.todoId` is `undefined`

Comment: I actually used todo.todoId for the key as you can see in the code snippet in my question. It sadly does not work :/

Comment: @TheProgrammer ok yea was on my mobile fixed my explanation ;) todo.todoId is undefined

Comment: That was the issue ! Thank you ! Had not seen the typo in  `this.todos.push({
                    text: this.newText,
                    done: false,
                    id: this.todoId++
                });`  `id:` should be `todoId:`

Answer (score 1):

You toggle the done value in child's todo component. It is better to make sure there is only a single source of truth. Which should be in parent data properties, todos.

What i did is pass down the todo object to child todo component as props. When done is press, emit the event like remove event, change the done value at parent like remove event as well.

---

**Edit for further explaination:**

Below is your child todo component.

```
Vue.component('todo',{
    props: ['text'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            done: false
        }
    },
    template: `
        <li> 
            <span v-on:click="done = !done" :class="{crossed: done}">
                {{text}}
            </span>
            <button v-on:click="$emit('remove')">Remove</button>
        </li>
    `
})
```

"done" is declared in data properties, not passed down from props.

You are actually declaring a brand new "done", I will called it as "childDone", this "childDone" is not related to your parent todos array "done". This "childDone" only live in this component, so whenever you toggle the value of this "childDone", parent's todos "done" wont be affected.

Yes, UI showed the todo has been crossed, because your UI also refer to "childDone" not parent "done". Parent "done" never passed down, so child todo component not render using parent's "done"

---

To explain why delete item 2, item 4 will become crossed.

1. todos.length = 4, render 4 components

   - component1:todo1:childDone=false
   - component2:todo2:childDone=false
   - component3:todo3:childDone=false
   - component4:todo4:childDone=false
2. crossed 3rd component,

   - component1:todo1:childDone=false
   - component2:todo2:childDone=false
   - component3:todo3:childDone=true
   - component4:todo4:childDone=false
3. delete 2nd todo element, todos.length = 3, render 3 components

   - component1:todo1:childDone=false
   - component2:todo3:childDone=false
   - component3:todo4:childDone=true
   - <s>compoenent4</s>(not render anymore because todos.length = 3)

```html
<div id="app">
    <todo-list>
    
    </todo-list>
</div>

<style>
    .crossed {
        text-decoration : line-through;
    }
    
    .todo:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>
    
Vue.component('todo-list',{

    data: function () {
        return {
            newText: '',
            todos:[],
            todoId: 0
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <form v-on:submit.prevent="addTodo">
                <input v-model="newText">
                <button>ADD TODO</button>
            </form>
            <ul>
                <todo class="todo" v-for="(todo,index) in todos" :todo="todo" :key="todo.todoId" @remove="removeTodo(index)" @done="doneTodo(index)"></todo>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        addTodo: function() {
            this.todos.push({
                text: this.newText,
                done: false,
                id: this.todoId++
            });
            this.newText = '';
        },
        removeTodo: function(index) {
            this.todos.splice(index,1);
        },
        doneTodo: function(index) {
            this.todos[index].done = !this.todos[index].done;
        }
    }

});

Vue.component('todo',{
    props: ['todo'],
    template: `
        <li> 
            <span v-on:click="$emit('done')" :class="{crossed: todo.done}">
                {{todo.text}}
            </span>
            <button v-on:click="$emit('remove')">Remove</button>
        </li>
    `
}) 

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
    



</script>
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing ^^ But it does not explain why my original approach wasn't working. I would like to understand why what I was doing wasn't properly working. After all, the done was still correctly set to false or true on click for the child component and thus uncrossed or crossed. It was only when elements above are removed that the an element below suddenly became crossed as if the done state was saved for the position in the array, not the child component itself. Why was that the case ?

Comment: I edited the answer, I try my best to explain it clearer.